# How to receive and parse requests as an HTTP server?

Tags: c++, http, sockets

For a class I have to implement an HTTP web server in C++. I currently have the server to the point that it can listen and accept connections, but I can't figure out how to accept data and parse it. When I send a request I get an error saying "Transport endpoint is nt connected." Here's what my code looks like so far:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // parse CLI args
    if (argc != 3) { /** change to 3 once DOCROOT is added */
        cout << "invalid arguments" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    const char *DOCROOT = argv[1];
    const char *PORT = argv[2];

    // declare vars....from beej's so some not in use yet
    int sockfd, new_fd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes = 1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // try getaddrinfo
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(nullptr, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through getaddrinfo response and bind when possible
    for (p=servinfo; p!=nullptr; p=p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (::bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    if (p == nullptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /** choose backlog number and declare constant */
    if (listen(sockfd, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, nullptr) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections on port %s...\n", PORT);


    while(true) { /** this will be the main accept loop */
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
                  get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
                  s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        // receive
        char recvbuf[1024];
        int recvbuflen = 1024;
        int request = recv(sockfd, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);

        if (request == -1) perror("error receiving data");

        if(send(new_fd, "Data received", 15, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
        close(new_fd);
        exit(0);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're trying to read from `sockfd` instead of `new_fd`. If recommended using more distinct names like `listener` and `connection` to help avoid confusion

Comment: Given that you don''t make any attempt to parse the data it is unclear what specific problems you have in parsing the data. If the problem is that you don't understand what data to expect please study the actual HTTP standard for details.